# How do I seperate the part in the middle in a clock mechanism?

Tags: repair

This is a torn down clock mechanism. How do I seperate the brass looking part in the middle from the black casing? It isn't push fit, so I'm assuming that it's threaded or something like that. Any ideas?

[image: Image description]

[image: Image description]

Comment: Probably glued in. And you might find this closed as off-topic.

Comment: which part do you want to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close up of the brass piece seems to indicate that it has a hex shaped flange that fits into an opening in the plastic that is shaped like a 12-point socket tool.

[image]

This hex keeps the part from turning. The stem of the brass piece, which is round, likely has a external rib that is tapered to allow the part to be pressed into the plastic and then the rib digs into the plastic to keep the part from popping back out.

[image]

Parts like this can have the rib be an interference fit in the hole the part is pressed onto or the rib may come all the way through the plastic and bear against the surface around the hole. In the latter case the stem of the part would protrude above the plastic surface some. It is hard to tell from your pictures if it protrudes or not.

Answer (score 1):

The brass part may be ultrasonically welded into the plastic piece. The part is pressed into place under pressure with it being vibrated at the ultrasonic frequency. This causes the plastic to soften and flows around the brass part locking it into place. The brass piece often is made with groves or knurling on the sides which give the plastic something to flow around and keep the part in place.

In this case the hex shape on one side is part of the grip system that ensures that the brass part does not turn.

If you have ever used plastic project boxes they often have brass inserts that accept the screws that hold the lid on. These inserts are installed just like I describe above.

This all drives to the conclusion that if you try to remove the brass insert you will almost certainly destroy the black plastic piece. If not destroyed you would have to find some messy way to try to glue the brass piece back in place - - - if the glue/epoxy used even will bond with the plastic.